# Convert cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication auth to Firebase JS-SDK auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am using mobile verification authentication by cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication`. The plugin is working fine, I can login, logout everything, which this defined in their documentation.

With this plugin I am using `Firebase JS-SDK` for firestore, As I am using third party authentication mechanism the firebase defined `onAuthStateChanged` is not working and it is obvious, and because of this `onAuthStateChanged` gives `null` for auth user.

I want to convert `cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication` auth user to `firebase` `js-sdk` auth user, or how can I use `cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication` auth user `request.auth.uid` in firebase security rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication` just for sending OTP by given method

```
cordova.plugins.firebase.auth
  .verifyPhoneNumber("+123456789", 30000)
  .then(function(verificationId) {
      // pass verificationId to signInWithVerificationId
  });
```

instead of using `cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication` `cordova.plugins.firebase.auth.signInWithVerificationId("djgfioerjg34", "123456");` for OTP verification, use `firebase-js-sdk` methods:

```
var credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationIdGeneratedByCordovaPlugin, OTP);
```

Then, you can sign in the user with the credential:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```